# What is a better way to write C++ bindings to C interface with function pointers?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, binding, function-pointers

There is some useful C library. I want to write the bindings to this library in C++. But the C API uses a lot of function pointers, that may be efficiently replaced by `std::function` in C++ API.

Since the `std::function` is not convertible to raw function pointer, I don't know what is a right way to go.

My options:

- **Use function pointers in C++ API** - this is very ugly and doubts the whole point of C++ bindings.
- **Rewrite some parts of original C internals** - then it's not really bindings, since I have to maintain more code then just API.

---

Are there any other options?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with function pointers per se. On the other hand, `std::function` is a heavy-weight, specialized tool that you should probably not using casually for just everything.

Comment: @KerrekSB I won't be able to use lambdas and `std::bind` - that is not a good thing. One of the reasons for C++ API is a some kind of "comfort". Of course, I can leave the overloads with function pointers - for efficiency.

Comment: Does the C API in question have an extra userdata parameter? If not, you're out of luck.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Some functions do, some not.

Comment: Does the C API give you a (void*) user data argument?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes You may try to give an answer about situation, when there is extra userdata param - it may be helpful for other C APIs, but not mine.